# Having trouble to run a program in C#

Tags: c#

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KV7Q7.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApYcc.png)

I was trying to run a program on C#.
Anyone know what the reason is and what the solution is?

Comment: Do not post error as images, please copy error message to your question.

Answer (score 0):

you must install net core SDK[64x] from here. after that run your program. sometimes need to close your visual studio.

[Microsoft Link](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/3.1)